# Store string with numbers as an integer array

Tags: c, arrays, c-strings, strtol

I'm writing a program in C where there's a user input. This input is a string with integer values separated by a space. The numbers (except the first one) have to be stored in an integer array. The first number indicates how many numbers have to be stored (so the size of the array).

What's the easiest way to do this in C? Here's an example:

```
input--> "5 76 35 95 14 20"

array--> {76, 35, 95, 14, 20}
```

I've been searching around but I can't find a solution to my question. At the moment, I've tried to store the values of the input in a char array and, when there's a space, I convert this string to an integer using `atoi()` and I add it to the integer array. But it prints strange values. This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char text[10];
    scanf("%s", text);

    int nums[4];
    int indNs = 0;

    char lastNum[10];
    int indLN = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if(text[i] == ' ')
        {
            nums[indNs] = atoi(lastNum);
            indNs++;

            sprintf(lastNum, "%s", "");
            indLN = 0;
        } else
        {
            lastNum[indLN] = text[i];
            indLN++;
        }
    }

    nums[indNs] = atoi(lastNum);

    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", nums[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: `fgets` then `sscanf` in loop is the easiest one.

Comment: Like `int array[5]; int unused; sscanf(input, "%d %d %d %d %d %d", &unused, &array[0], &array[1], &array[2], &array[3], &array[4])`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56594003/6699433

Comment: @Kamilcuk what about 10 3 6 4 6 4 5 5 4 5 4

Comment: @Carcigenicate I uploaded the post.

Comment: @ARD Look at my link. I answered a similar question earlier.

Comment: @ARD Ups. I picked the wrong link even if that one also helps, but this is better: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56570260/6699433

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use `scanf` to read space separated input as `scanf` will stop reading once it hits white space.

```
scanf("%s", text); //Wrong, always reads only first number.
```

You could use `fgets` followed by `sscanf` with `%n` in loop.

```
char buf[100];

int *array = NULL;
int numElements = 0;
int numBytes = 0;
if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin)) {

   char *p = buf;
   if (1 == sscanf(buf, "%d%n", &numElements,&numBytes)){
       p +=numBytes;
       array = malloc(sizeof(int)*numElements);
       for (int i = 0;i<numElements;i++){
         sscanf(p,"%d%n", &array[i],&numBytes);
         p +=numBytes;
         printf("%d,", array[i]);
       }
   }
}
```

> `%n` returns number of bytes read so far thus advance the `buf` number
>   of bytes read so far.

---

If you are not dealing with `strings` and directly reading from `stdin` you don't need all that mess.

```
int *array = NULL;
int numElements = 0;


scanf("%d", &numElements);
array = malloc(sizeof(int)*numElements);

for(int i=0;i<numElements;i++)
{
    scanf("%d", &array[i]);
    printf("%d ", array[i]);
}
```

Comment: There is no need to read the whole line into a buffer, just read each integer separately using `scanf("%d", &foo)`

Comment: Oh, and there is a `malloc()` but no `free()`.

Answer (score 2):

In this case you can use for example the standard C function `strtol` declared in header `<stdlib.h>`.

For example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( void )
{
    const char *s = "5 76 35 95 14 20";

    char *p = ( char * )s;

    int n = ( int )strtol( p, &p, 10 );

    int *a = malloc( n * sizeof( int ) );

    for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        a[i] = strtol( p, &p, 10 );
    }

    for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%d ", a[i] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );

    free( a );
}
```

The program output is

```
76 35 95 14 20
```

To read a string with blanks you should use the standard C function `fgets`.